# Query string in session data causes HMAC mismatch

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies, hmac

Using codeigniter framework version 2.2.1. Attempting to store query string within session data via:

```
$ci->session->set_userdata('parentCrumbs', array(
            '<a href="/store/items/' . $ci->input->server('QUERY_STRING') . '">Items</a>'
        ));
```

My session is abandoned and I receive a message within the error log stating:

> Session: HMAC mismatch. The session cookie data did not match what was expected.

Is it not feasible to store a querystring within a session cookie? Is there something simple I'm missing or don't understand?

Comment: Have you read this already ? https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/3094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been encrypting my session cookies since this application is currently still in development and it has been useful up to this point to see the values of the session cookie from within the browser...However it turns out that this issue is not present when encrypting the session cookie via:

```
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']      = TRUE;
```

From within /application/config/config.php